# Optimizing and caching large amounts of AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, web, caching

Let's say I have a website which displays lists of favorite books, which can number in the 1000s. Each book has an ID and a bunch of metadata associated with it. I need to load the full data set because I want to enable things like sorting and making charts.

At the moment I just have a single AJAX API request that grabs the list of books with their associated metadata in one go. However, I think it might actually be better to just get a list of their IDs first (faster to generate and quicker to transfer) and then do a separate API call which just returns the metadata given the ID.

If I make one request per book I can cache all of them easily but I'll also potentially need to send 1000s of requests. If I make a single request with all the IDs at once instead caching that won't really make sense any more and I might need to transfer quite a bit of data in one go.

I could also split the list into chunks and query 10s or 100s of books at a time, but again that won't be very cacheable.

What's the best solution here? Query everything in one go but then manually cache items in local storage? Or something else?

Comment: How about doing the sorting and chart-making (or at least extracting the chart-relevant parts) on the server?

Comment: What exactly do you want to optimise for? Time until everything is loaded? Time until the first bit can be displayed? Low resource usage? And wrt. caching: how/when/how often does the data change?

Comment: Thank you for your comments - in the end I decided to go for a server-side implementation after all.